# Makefile process different files in different steps

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu, autotools, tntnet

I have the following makefile using GNU autotools:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects

bin_PROGRAMS = app

app_SOURCES = \
    core/main.cpp

nodist_app_SOURCES = \
    index.cpp \
    index.ecpp.js.cpp

AM_INCLUDES = -I$(top_srcdir)/src

index.cpp: index.ecpp
    $(ECPPC) index.ecpp -o index.cpp

index.ecpp.js.cpp: index.ecpp.js
    $(ECPPC) -b index.ecpp.js

index.ecpp:
    vulcanize -o index.ecpp core/view/index.html --inline --strip --csp
```

What happens (in this case only for index.html):

- vulcanize creates a .ecpp and a .ecpp.js file out of a .html file
- those newly created files are compiled to .cpp files by the ecppc compiler
- the created .cpp files are compiled with g++

I have a lot of .html files which need to be processed, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Try wildcards maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either [Suffix rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) or [Pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html). In your case, both should do the job equally well.

The only difference is that Pattern rules are GNU-Make-specific (not compatible with Unix make), though the GNU manual I linked to discourages the use of the Suffix rules, probably because its possible use cases are a lot more limited than those of Pattern rules.